# How to use Oozie action with input path depending on flag

Tags: conditional-statements, oozie

I have an oozie action that has a defined input path. In case this path does not exist I want to set the input to some default path.

Is there a way to have the path depending on a condition? I know I can replicate the action for each possible input and have a condition that routes to the correct action. However, this is not scalable when having many conditional paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oozie allows you to use EL expressions, which includes the conditional operator `?:`. This makes it fairly straight-forward to implement a default path when the specified path does not exist:

```
${fs:exists(specified_path) ? specified_path : default_path}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can have a decision node as below. In which you control your actions if input path found and not found. If found you can use the path in your action. If not found you set the default input path in the next action which is having the control.

```
<decision name="isFileExists">
         <switch>
            <case to="yourNextAction">
              ${fs:exists(yourInputPath)}
            </case>
            <default to="yourNextActionIfInputNotFound" />
         </switch>
</decision>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
How do I set the default input path inside the workflow?
It seems like your suggestion means replicating the action for each possible input. In other words it seems like "yourNextAction" and "yourNextActionIfInputNotFound" are the almost replicates.